# Using TimeZones on website using ASP.Net 3.5 / SQL Server 2005

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, .net-3.5, timezone, utc

I am trying to determine, how I should implement local time in a web-app. All users are logged in, there are no anonymous users. They will need to see all time-values in their local time.

Is this how it should be done?

1. All DateTime values are saved as UTC-time in database
2. Each user has a UTC-Offset value stored in his profile
3. When displaying a datetime-value, I take the value from the database, and apply the users offset.

Is this the way to go? Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Don't store a UTC offset for the user - that's not enough to know the full time zone information. You should store their [Olson time zone ID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zoneinfo), e.g. "Europe/London". Then you can display any UTC time in the local time, taking into account historical changes, daylight savings etc.

EDIT: It looks like the `TimeZoneInfo` ID isn't actually in the normal Olson format - but so long as there's something sensible you can display to the user (as a choice), and an ID you can retrieve the zone from later on, that's probably okay... you may have difficulties if you need to interoperate with other systems later though.

You should *ask* the user for their time zone (possibly trying to guess it first through JavaScript) - they will have more information than you do.

You should investigate the [TimeZoneInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timezoneinfo.aspx) class for more on this - I can't say I've used it much myself, but it's the way to go as of .NET 3.5. In particular, [FindSystemTimeZoneById](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timezoneinfo.findsystemtimezonebyid.aspx) and [GetSystemTimeZones](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timezoneinfo.getsystemtimezones.aspx) will be important.

Time zones are a pain in general, but at least `TimeZoneInfo` gives a lot more support than the old `TimeZone` type.

Comment: The world should have one language, one time, one system for measuring stuff etc... Sigh! ;)

Great post, Jon.

Answer (score 0):

That sounds like the most straightforward way to me. The only slip ups I could see occurring are some areas (such as parts of Indiana and I think all of Arizona) don't cooperate with daylight savings time, so you'll have to take extra precautions displaying the correct time for them.