# How do you handle different time zones in a website?

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime, timezone

I got [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/644342/using-timezones-on-website-using-asp-net-3-5-sql-server-2005) from [Kjensen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/77884/kjensen) and read the answers, but this is a different webapp

I'm running scheduled events that process incoming orders, set Picking material, manage Track & Trace numbers, etc ... and I do this at a specific time of the day (set in Administration Panel)

My server is in UK (DiscountAsp.net) but I'm 2 hours ahead.

What I really wanted is, every time I call `DateTime.Now` that would be automatically changed to my time instead of Local Server Time. This should handle Daylight savings as well.

I thought about making a Extension to simply call `DateTime.MyLocalTime` and there use TimeInfo to add / subtract the correct hours.

In good old days I did this in Global.asa (ASP) ... I just wanted to know if there is a better way to handle this.

Comment: Managing timezones, date-shifts across timezones, and daylight-savings time has consumed more hours and made my development life more miserable than almost any other issue.  It becomes even more "fun" when the data is collected in one timezone, stored in another, retrieved by a webserver in yet another timezone, and shown to the user on a browser in yet ANOTHER timezone.  My heart goes out to you!  :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead of saving to a particular timezone (IST, GMT, EST, etc), I find it a pretty good idea to store as UTC.

Storing as UTC simply removes the issues of the Daylight Savings boundaries - days with 23 hours or 25 hours.

Store user's timezone based either on their preferences, or auto-magically guesstimated.

Then do the arithmetic when you save and retrieve data and display appropriately.